# Conditional expectation given sum

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

There are two random variables $X$ and $Y$, both of them distributed standard normal. Based on $X$ and $Y$, define $Z = X + a  Y$ for $a$ a known parameter.

I'm interested in $E(X | Z)$.

It seems to me that a starting point could be the approach taken [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206812/conditional-expectations-given-sum-of-i-i-d). So I start with:

$ Z = E( X | Z) + a E(Y | Z) $

and then I write out the expectation terms explicitly, hoping to find an easy substitution:

$ E(X | Z) = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x f(x)f(\frac{Z-x}{a})dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)f(\frac{Z-x}{a})dx} $

and

$ E(Y | Z) = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y f(y)f(Z-ay)dy}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y)f(Z-ay)dy} $

But here I'm stuck, I can't find an substition that would allow me to express $E(Y|Z)$ in terms of $E(X|Z)$, in order to plug in above. So how to continue from here?

**Edit:**

For $a =1$, one can simply use $E(X|Z) = E(Y | Z)$, plug in above, and obtain $E(X|Z) = Z/2$.

I conjecture that in general, it holds that $$E(X|Z) = \frac{Z}{1 + a^2}.$$ This is supported by several numerical simulations I made.

This would require showing that $E(Y|Z) = a E(X | Z)$. In case substituting in the integral does not help, how else could I show that?

Comment: Nope.  That is not going anywhere helpful.  With a change of variables we find that:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y\mid Z)&=\dfrac{\int_\Bbb R y f(y)f(Z-ay)\,\mathrm d y}{\int_\Bbb R f(y)f(Z-ay)\,\mathrm d y}\\&=\dfrac{\int_\Bbb R \tfrac{Z-x}a f(\tfrac{Z-x}a)f(x)\,\mathrm d \tfrac{Z-x}a}{\int_\Bbb R f(\tfrac{Z-x}a)f(x)\,\mathrm d \tfrac{Z-x}a}\\&=\frac Za-\dfrac{\int_\Bbb R xf(\tfrac{Z-x}a)f(x)\,\mathrm d x}{a\int_\Bbb R f(\tfrac{Z-x}a)f(x)\,\mathrm d x}\\&=\tfrac 1a(Z-\mathsf E(X\mid Z))\\[2ex]\therefore\quad Z&=\mathsf E(X\mid Z)+a\mathsf E(Y\mid Z)&\text{uh...yeah}\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes I see, too bad. Well then maybe some other substitution? Or using symmetry of the normal PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$. This can [easily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables) be found since the $cov(X,Z)=1$ and hence

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc} X \\ Z \end{array} \right) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right) , \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1+a^2 \end{array} \right)  \right)$$

Now we can simply apply the formula for the [conditional expectation from a bivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#In_the_general_case) and obtain

$$E(X | Z) = \frac{Z}{1+a^2}.$$

**Some background notes:**

[Lecture notes on multivariate normal distribution](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Esteffen/teaching/bs2HT9/gauss.pdf)

[Marginal and conditional distributions of multivariate normal distribution](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html)

and Chapter 3 (Theorem 3.3.4) in Tong, Y.L., 2012. *The multivariate normal distribution*. Springer Science & Business Media.