# When are conditional expectations equal?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

As a sort of a follow-up and a generalization from a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842364/conditional-expectation-of-independent-variables/1842770?noredirect=1#comment3771032_1842770), suppose that we have two independent, identically distributed random variables $X, Y$ and a third random variable $W$. Is it true that $\mathbb E[X \mid W]=\mathbb E[Y \mid W]$?

More in general, what conditions are to be imposed in order to have equality? When $W=X+Y$ the statement is true. But supposed there is no relation, a priori between $W$ and $X, Y$. What can we say in this case?

Comment: If $W$ is a symmetric function in $X$ and $Y$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Did you read [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842364/conditional-expectation-of-independent-variables#comment3768672_1842364) on a previous comment of yours?

Comment: @Did, yes, if I understand correctly you are saying the following: If $X, Y$ are i.i.d., then the pairs $(X, X+Y), (Y, X+Y)$ have the same distribution. To be honest, I still do not see why. My background here is insufficient. Could you please suggest me a book where this statement is proved exhaustively? That would help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: "To be honest, I still do not see why" Note that $(X,X+Y)=g(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X+Y)=g(Y,X)$ for some function $g$ that you can probably define yourself, and that $(X,Y)$ and $(Y,X)$ are identically distributed, hence $g(X,Y)$ and $g(Y,X)$ are identically distributed, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $W = X$. Then $E[X\mid W] = X$ whereas $E[Y\mid W] = E[Y]$. There is too much freedom in the choice of $W$. You have to control for some property to arrive at a useful conclusion. Otherwise, any conclusion is possible as the example above shows.