# Show that $E[X\mid X+Y] = \frac{X+Y}{2}$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and identically distributed
  random variables.  Show that
$$E[X\mid X+Y] = \frac{X+Y} 2$$

Comment: Do you know that $E[X|X+Y] = E[Y|X+Y]$ in that case?

Comment: oh okay, because its IID? I didn't really know that

Comment: People usually refer to it as being obvious. I asked for a rigorous proof on this site a while ago. You might want to have a look but I guess you would be allowed to just use this result. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1945550/explain-why-ex-1x-1x-2-ex-2x-1x-2-if-x-1-x-2-are-i-i-d

Comment: I looked at it, but you see that Michael's post below makes it even easier

Comment: No it doesn't. It uses the same identity I proposed just without proof. This is fine of course, you can use that if you want. But thats not easier but just skipping part of the proof.

Comment: I see, I guess I didn't get it at first. I am hoping I can use it without the proof.

Comment: Probably the reason for the votes to close the question as "off-topic" is that it's phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That tends to be frowned on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symmetry shows that $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+Y) = \operatorname{E}(Y\mid X+Y).$$ And clearly $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X+Y) + \operatorname{E}(Y\mid X+Y) = \operatorname{E}(X+Y\mid X+Y) = X+Y.$$
So these two things  are equal to each other and their sum is $X+Y$.