# If $(X,Z)=(Y,Z)$ in law and $h_1(X)=\mathbb{E}(g(Z)|X)$, $h_2(Y)=\mathbb{E}(g(Z)|Y)$, then $h_1(Y)=h_2(Y)$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be real valued random variables such that $(X,Z)=(Y,Z)$ in law.
>   Let $g$ be a bounded Borel function and define $h_1(X)=\mathbb{E}(g(Z)|X),h_2(Y)=\mathbb{E}(g(Z)|Y)$. Prove that $h_1(Y)=h_2(Y)$ a.s.

I'm able to prove that if I also suppose that the random variables are jointly absolutely continuous:

$$h_1(x)=\int g(z)f_{(Z|X)}(z,x)dz=\int g(z)\frac{f_{(Z,X)}(z,x)}{\int f_{(Z,X)}(z',x)dz'}dz\\=\int g(z)\frac{f_{(Z,Y)}(z,x)}{\int f_{(Z,Y)}(z',x)dz'}dz=h_2(x)$$

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show the case you can do. (It is plausible than only cosmetic modifications to your method will allow to solve the general case.)

Comment: I'll do that but I don't think that you can adapt the argument.

Comment: Ah, but this is because you blindly apply ready-made formulas, I thought you were going to apply the general definition of the conditional expectation E(U|V)... What is this definition, already?

Comment: $E(U|V)=Z$ iff $E(U1_B(V))=E(Z1_B(V))$ for all $B\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Excellent. And?

Comment: I'm not able to connect this definition to the function $h_1$ and $h_2$

Comment: Maybe the following relation could help us: $$E(h_2(Y)1_B(Y))=E(g(Z)1_B(Y))=E(g(Z)1_B(X))=E(h_1(X)1_B(X))$$ for all $B\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Is it enough to conclude?

Comment: Not yet, but if you choose $B=\{y\in\mathbb R\,;\,h_1(y)\geqslant h_2(y)+\epsilon\}$, then...

Comment: I don't know how to use your hint because I have two different random variable $X$ and $Y$

Comment: ?? The Borel set $B$ is also $B=\{x\in\mathbb R\,;\,h_1(x)\geqslant h_2(x)+\epsilon\}$.

Comment: Is this true $E(h_1(X)1_B(X)-h_2(Y)1_B(Y))=E(h_1(Y)-h_2(Y)1_{h_1(Y)-h_2(Y)\geq\epsilon})$?

Comment: The point you seem to be missing is that $X=Y$ in law hence $E(g(X))=E(g(Y))$ for every $g$.

Comment: We have that (X,Z)=(Y,Z) not X=Y

Comment: Ah. Then your first task is to show that indeed, if (X,Z)=(Y,Z) in law then X=Y in law, always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47716/discussion-between-mr-brown-and-did).

Comment: "Let us continue this discussion in chat." What for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that, if $(X, Z)=(Y, Z)$ in law, then, for any bounded Borel functions $f_1: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have that 
\begin{align*}
E(f_1(X, Z))=E(f_1(Y, Z))\tag{1}
\end{align*} 
and that 
\begin{align*}
E(f_2(X))=E(f_2(Y)).\tag{2}
\end{align*} 
Consequently, for any Borel set $A$, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{Y \in A} h_2(Y) dP &= \int_{Y \in A} E(g(Z)\mid Y) dP\\
&=\int_{Y \in A} g(Z) dP \\
&=\int_{\Omega} 1_{Y\in A}g(Z)  dP\\
&=E(1_{Y\in A}g(Z))\\
&=E(1_{X\in A}g(Z)) \qquad (\text{From } (1))\\
&=\int_{X\in A}g(Z) dP\\
&=\int_{X\in A}E(g(Z)\mid X) dP\\
&=\int_{X\in A}h_1(X) dP\\
&=E(h_1(X) 1_{X\in A})\\
&=E(h_1(Y) 1_{Y\in A}) \qquad (\text{From } (2))\\
&=\int_{Y \in A} h_1(Y) dP.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $h_1(Y)=h_2(Y)$ a.s.

Comment: How can I use that to compute the following expectation: $E(T|T_1)$ where $T=T_1+...+T_n$ and $T_1,...,T_n$ are i.i.d.

Comment: which expectation?

Comment: I complete my question

Comment: I lost your link:(

Comment: That should be easy: $E(T\mid T_1) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(T_i  \mid T_1) = T_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n E(T_i) = T_1 + (n-1)E(T_1)$.

Comment: That [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842364/conditional-expectation-of-independent-variables/1842770#1842770) does not appear related to this question, so I have removed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47715/discussion-between-mr-brown-and-gordon).