# Property of conditional expectation ( symmetry )

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

How  to  prove  this  property  of  conditional  expectation  if  $X$  and  $Y$  are  independent  and  identically  distributed  random  variables
$E[X|X+Y]=E[Y|X+Y]$?

Comment: sure that not some information missing?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent and identically distributed

Comment: Sorry  for  missing   an  information!

Comment: See answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842364/conditional-expectation-of-independent-variables/1842770#1842770).