# Follow up question on application of Fubini in an old answer

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am working with the same problem and have a follow up question to an old solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1842770/1100158. Here they use Fubini's, but nowhere does it say that the random variables, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, have finite expectation. Is there a reason why $E(Z_1I_{Z_1+Z_2\in A})$ is finite for any borel set $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? Clearly $A=\mathbb{R}$ with $|EZ_1|=\infty$ no longer works with this argument.

I ask because in the statement of my problem, we have defined expectations, so not necessarily finite.

Comment: If each of the two expectations is finite, both are equal; otherwise, they are both infinite.

Comment: I understand that identically distributed random variables have the same expectation, but I don't see how that justifies using Fubini when the expectations are both infinite

Comment: I think Fubini–Tonelli theorem is called Fubini here. You may see the section on Fubini–Tonelli theorem in the link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: The assumption of integrability of $Z_1$ (needed for the application of Fubini) is missing both from the original question and from the solution you are interested in.