# Let $X_1, \cdots ,X_n$ be independent and identically distributed random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Find $E[X_1|X_1 + \cdots +X_n=x] $

This is pretty new concept for me so any help would be very helpful.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/conditional-expectation-for-a-sum-of-iid-random-variables-e-xi-mid-xi-eta-e

Comment: You need to assume that $X_1$ is integrable and this fact should be stated in the assumption.

Answer (score 8):

Hint:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_i|\sum_{k=1}^n X_k=x]= \mathbb{E}[X_j|\sum_{k=1}^n X_k=x]$$

You might want to use linearity of expectation and sum of $n$ copies of them for a start.

Comment: Maybe nitpicking here, but did you on purpose not write '$X_k$' in the sum? :) nice hint btw

Comment: oops, that was a careless mistake. Thanks.