# Conditional density given sum

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

### Set-up

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables having densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, which also have a joint density, with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

### Question

I am trying to derive a formula for the density $X$ conditional on $X+Y$ following the argument in [Conditional density of Sum of two independent and continuous random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473790/conditional-density-of-sum-of-two-independent-and-continuous-random-variables)

Questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771659/for-i-i-d-random-variables-x-and-y-is-ex-mid-sigmaxy-fracxy2?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771659/for-i-i-d-random-variables-x-and-y-is-ex-mid-sigmaxy-fracxy2?noredirect=1&lq=1) consider the **conditional expectation** given the sum.
I am trying to derive **the density** and I am very confused.

---

### Calculations

We want to find a function $f_{X|X+Y}$ such that
$$
E[1_{\{X\in A\}}|\sigma(X+Y)](\omega)
\stackrel{P-\text{a.s.}}{=}
 E[1_{\{X\in A\}}|X+Y=t]|_{t=X(\omega)+Y(\omega)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{A}(x)\,f_{X|X(\omega)+Y(\omega)}(x)dx
\quad\text{for any }A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
From the factorization lemma, there exists a measurable function $\varphi_A\colon\mathbb{R}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that
$$
E[1_{\{X\in A\}}|X+Y=t]=\varphi_A(t).
$$
Now, $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ implies $\{X+Y\in B\}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and thus from the definition of the conditional expectation we have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\int_{\mathbb{R}}
    1_A(x)1_{B}(x+y)f_X(x)f_Y
(y)\,dxdy&\\=
E[1_{\{X\in A\}}\,1_{\{X+Y\in B\}}]
&=E[(E[1_{\{X\in A\}}|\sigma(X+Y)])1_{\{X+Y\in B\}}]\\
&=E[\varphi_A(X+Y)1_{\{X+Y\in B\}}]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi_A(t)1_{B}(t)f_{X+Y}(t)dt \\
%&\stackrel{\text{also we have}}{=}E\Bigg[\Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{A}(x)\,f_{X|X(\omega)+Y(\omega)}(x)dx\Bigg)\,1_{\{X+Y\in B\}}\Bigg]\\
%&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{R}}
%  1_{A}(x)\,f_{X|x'+y}(x)dx\Bigg)1_{B}(x'+y)f_X(x')f_Y(y)\,dx'dy
\end{align}
From here the aforementioned answer would obtain a form of $\varphi_A$ by an identification. But here $f_{X+Y}$ is the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$, and I do not know how to proceed...

Comment: Proceed using that convolution.  $f_{\small X+Y}(t)=\int_\Bbb R f_{\small X}(x)\, f_{\small Y}(t-x)\,\mathrm d x$

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get it anywhere.