# Find the expected value for these random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with finite expected value. Find
$\mathbb{E}[X_{1}|(X_{1}+X_{2}+ ... + X_{n})=x]$.
Assuming that $f_{(X_{1}+X_{2}+ ... + X_{n})}(x)\neq 0$, I must have the expected value is $\frac{x}{n}$. ¿Could you give me a hint to do it, please?

Comment: Use the facts that $$E(X_1+ \ldots + X_n|X_1 + \ldots + X_n =x)=x$$ $$E(X_1|X_1+ \ldots + X_n=x)=E(X_j|X_1+\ldots + X_n=x)$$ for any $j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$

Comment: The issue I have with the above comment (and the current answer) is that, while correct, they don't explain how some of the assumptions are used. The independence is necessary, but that's not apparent from the argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional expectation for a sum of iid random variables: $E(\xi\mid\xi+\eta)=E(\eta\mid\xi+\eta)=\frac{\xi+\eta}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/conditional-expectation-for-a-sum-of-iid-random-variables-e-xi-mid-xi-eta-e)

Comment: Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374997/119261.

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry,
$$\mathbb E[X_1\mid X_1+\dots+X_n]=\mathbb E[X_2\mid X_1+\dots+X_n]=\dots=\mathbb E[X_n\mid X_1+\dots+X_n].$$
But by linearity
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[X_i\,\middle|\,\sum_{j=1}^n X_j=x\right]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\,\middle|\,\sum_{j=1}^nX_j=x\right]=x,$$
so we have $\mathbb E[X_i\mid X_1+\dots+X_n=x]=\frac{x}{n}$.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out where/if the independence assumption is used ("by symmetry" can be a bit of a magic wand).

Comment: Jlammy and @ClementC. could you please look at my recent question?

Comment: I'm also curious where/if the independence assumption is used.

Comment: @PedroAmaral It has to be: if not, the first fact stated doesn't hold. For instance, take $X_1,X_2,X_3$ all (marginally) uniform on $\{-1,1\}$, with $X_3$ independent of $(X_1,X_2)$ but $X_1=-X_2$ always. Then $X_1+X_2+X_3=X_3$ (the first two cancel), so $$\mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid X_1+X_2+X_3] = \mathbb{E}[X_1 \mid X_3] = 0$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[X_2 \mid X_1+X_2+X_3] = \mathbb{E}[X_2 \mid X_3] = 0$$ but $$\mathbb{E}[X_3 \mid X_1+X_2+X_3] = \mathbb{E}[X_3 \mid X_3] = X_3 \in \{-1,1\}$$

Comment: @ClementC. Ah very tricky! Is there a simple way to prove that the expectations are equal when the $X_i$'s are all independent? I came up with the following but it is somewhat messy: 

$$
f_{X_1,\sum X_i}(x_1, x)
$$
$$
= \idotsint f_{X_1, \sum X_i,X_2, ...,X_n}(x_1, x, x_2, .., x_n)dx_2...dx_n
$$

$$ 
= \idotsint \delta_{x,\sum x_i} \cdot f_{X_1,X_2, ...,X_n}(x_1, x_2, .., x_n)dx_2...dx_n
$$

$$
= \idotsint \delta_{x,\sum x_i} \cdot f_{X_1,X_2, ...,X_n}(x_1, x_2, .., x_n)dx_2...dx_n
$$

$$
= \idotsint \delta_{x,\sum x_i} \cdot f(x_1)f(x_2)...f(x_n)dx_2...dx_n
$$

Comment: @PedroAmaral I think the notion needed here is [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), which is implied by i.i.d. Once you have that, the symmetry argument is basically by definition.