# How to compute conditional expectation given sum of variables?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given i.i.d. $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n$ I wonder how I can compute
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_1 + 2X_2|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k).
$$
I realize that I should expand it as
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_1|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k) + 2\mathbb{E}(X_2|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k).
$$
But what to do next? How can I extract knowledge from the sum?

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/q/78546/321264, you can see that $E\left[X_k\mid \sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right]=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for every $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For i.i.d samples:

$\mathbb{E}(X_1|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k)=\mathbb{E}(X_2|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k)=...=\mathbb{E}(X_n|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k)$

$\mathbb{E}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$

Comment: How to proof the first row?

Comment: @Nou It should be clear by symmetry.