# conditional expectation of random walk

Tags: probability

Suppose I have $\{X_i\}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $n$; I know that the $X_i$ are all independent and identically distributed, and also $P(X_i=1)=p$,$P(X_i=-1)=q$. I want to calculate the conditional expectation $E[X_1\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n]$; how can I do that?

Comment: Hello Vadim. What do you know about the conditional expectation ?

Comment: First, lets recall definition E[X|A]=$\sum_{p \in \Omega} p*P(X=p|A)$, this is when we have X - discrete,so in my case. So i must do something like that $E[X_1|X_1+...+X_n=x](x) = -P(X_1=-1|X_1+...+X_n=x)+P(X_1=1|X_1+...+X_n=x)$

Comment: $E[X_1|X_1+...+X_n]=\frac 1 n (X_1+...+X_n)$ whenvever $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. with finite mean.

Comment: @geetha290krm, can you please explain why is that so?

Comment: The reason is the joint distrbution of $(X_i)$ remains invariant under permutations. This result has appeared many times on this site. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/conditional-expectation-for-a-sum-of-iid-random-variables-e-xi-mid-xi-eta-e